# How to detect eyes, mouth and chin on a Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, face-detection

I am working on an Android app where I need to detect the coordinates of the eyes, mouth and chin on a bitmap. I have seen other apps do it like [Make Me Bearded](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.beard&hl=en) use similar detection. I have worked with [Face Detector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html#) but it only gives me the location for the eyes. Is there some algorithm or library that can help me with this? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use openCV, it has an android edition:

http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html